# What does "ClassName objName; objName(1);" mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, instantiation

I have this code:

```
ClassName objName;
objName(1);
```

How should I understand it? Does the first line create an object (called `objName` and belonging to `ClassName` class) using the constructor that does not take any arguments? And then the second line calls the constructor that takes one integer arguments? So, it means that, in fact, on the second line we destroy the old object and create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line does as you say; it creates an object of type `ClassName` and calls it `objName`. It is constructed with its default constructor (which takes no arguments).

The second line is calling the overloaded `operator()` for that class. This allows it to be called like a function. The argument `1` is being passed to that overloaded operator.

Here's an example:

```
struct foo
{
  operator()(int x) { std::cout << x * 2 << std::endl; }
};
```

This `foo` type is overloading `operator()` which takes an `int`. It then prints out the value of the passed `int` multiplied by two. Here's an example of its use:

```
foo f;
f(5); // Prints out 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
objName(1);
```

This line implies that the `operator ()` is overloaded for ClassName.

Answer (score 1):

Does `ClassName` have an overloaded `operator()(int)`?

This would explain the behaviour - in this case this is simply function call